# How to check for migrations without running Add-Migration

Tags: entity-framework

I'd like to be able to check if a migration needs to be created, without having to run Add-Migration. There doesn't seem to be a command to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: I cant try now but how about running update-database without Add-Migration? It will give a warning not sure if the warning will be shown if there is no change in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that running `Add-Migration` doesn't actually execute anything against your database, the easiest thing to do is just run `Add-Migration`.  If the resulting migration class is empty, undo/discard your changes.  No harm done.